# accented letters in Python

Tags: python, syntax-error

Is there any way to define a string with accented letters in python?
An extreme example is this one:

```
message = "ÂÃÄÀÁÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýþÿ"
```

Error:

```
SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xc2'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When souce code contains something else than ASCII, you have to add a line to tell the python interpreter:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8
```

Read more in [PEP-0263](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) for the exact rules how to include the encoding hint in a magic comment.

Answer (score 4):

If you use Python 3.x you can use accented (Unicode) strings without doing anything special. If you are using Python 2.x, use `u` prefix to denote Unicode:

```
message = u"ÂÃÄÀÁÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýþÿ"
```

Also remember to include the following line *at the top of* your script:

```
# coding=utf-8
```

[PEP-0263](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) explains this in detail:

> To define a source code encoding, a magic comment must
>       be placed into the source files either as first or second
>       line in the file, such as:
>
> ```
> # coding=<encoding name>
> ```

Comment: PEP 0263 specifies it as `coding`. Are you sure you saved the file in UTF-8 format? What do you exactly mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: The correct method is `coding` per documentation, but most probably your editor/IDE recognizes `encoding` and saves the file in UTF-8 format.